# Download form textarea as an XML file. Works in IE10 but not Chrome35 or Firefox30

Tags: javascript, html, xml, cross-browser

Trying to create a button (or link) to download data from inside a html form textarea and be saved as an XML file. I could explain why, but it'll take forever.

Here's my working (in IE10 only) text example. I'd like it to work in Chrome and Firefox as well, but so far no luck, any ideas?

I don't need anything fancy, just throw the data in a variable, put the variable into a new file, and prompt the SaveAs filename.xml

```
<html>

<head>
<script lang="javascript">
function download(){
     var xmlContent = document.getElementById("Kitchen").innerHTML; //here we load our xml data 
     var blob = new Blob([xmlContent], {
         type: "text/xml;charset=utf-8;"
     });
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "SaveAsYourFileNameHere.xml");
}
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: rgb(225,225,225)">
<br>
<form id="House">
  <textarea id="Kitchen"cols="20" rows="10">This is the Kitchen</textarea>
</form>
<br>
<a href="#" onClick="download()">Download Xml</a><br>
<br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blob only works in IE, for FF and Chrome look into Data URI's

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function base64_encode(data) {
            //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/
            // original by: Tyler Akins (http://rumkin.com)
            // improved by: Bayron Guevara
            // improved by: Thunder.m
            // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
            // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
            // improved by: Rafa? Kukawski (http://kukawski.pl)
            // bugfixed by: Pellentesque Malesuada
            //   example 1: base64_encode('Kevin van Zonneveld');
            //   returns 1: 'S2V2aW4gdmFuIFpvbm5ldmVsZA=='
            //   example 2: base64_encode('a');
            //   returns 2: 'YQ=='

            var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
            var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
                    ac = 0,
                    enc = '',
                    tmp_arr = [];

            if (!data) {
                return data;
            }

            do { // pack three octets into four hexets
                o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
                o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
                o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

                bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;

                h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
                h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
                h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
                h4 = bits & 0x3f;

                // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
                tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
            } while (i < data.length);

            enc = tmp_arr.join('');

            var r = data.length % 3;

            return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
        }

        var str="Hi my name is Adam and I love Javascript";
        var str64=base64_encode(str);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
            var fileData = str;
            blobObject = new Blob([str]);
            a.onclick=function(){
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, 'MyFile.csv');
            }
        }else{
            a.setAttribute('href','data:text/csv;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22with%20spaces.csv%22%0D%0AContent-Language%3A%20en,%E2%88%9A;base64,' + str64,'MyFile.csv');
        }
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click to Download'));
        document.body.appendChild(a);
    </script>
```